# Suppress debug logs with slf4j simple logger

Tags: logging, slf4j, springfox

I am using slf4j-simple. How do I set the default log level for springfox to `info`, while keeping `debug` logs from all other sources?

The logger properties file is in this location:

```
src
  main
    resources
      simplelogger.properties
```

simplelogger.properties:

```
logging.level.springfox=info
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out
```

However, I am still getting excess `debug` level logs from springfox in the following form:

```
[main] DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelProvider - xxx
```

I can suppress all `debug` level logs by changing the second line in simplelogger.properties to `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info`, but I still want to keep some `debug` logs that are not generated by springfox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.slf4j.org/api/index.html?org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html);

> `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.a.b.c` - Logging detail level for a SimpleLogger instance named "a.b.c". Right-side value must be one of "trace", "debug", "info", "warn", "error" or "off". When a SimpleLogger named "a.b.c" is initialized, its level is assigned from this property

So, to set the log level for loggers in this package: `springfox` you should set this property in `simplelogger.properties`:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.springfox=info
```